# lxml: XPath and namespaces on an element

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, xml-namespaces

I am having trouble using an XPath query that returns an empty list as a result.

More specifically, the XML document is like:

```
<rpc-reply xmlns:junos="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/15.1X22/junos">
    <isis-database-information xmlns="http://xml.juniper.net/junos/15.1X22/junos-routing" junos:style="detail">
        <isis-database>
            <level>1</level>
            <isis-database-entry>
                <lsp-id>xxx.00-00</lsp-id>
                <sequence-number>0xc2d6</sequence-number>
                <checksum>0xe1d1</checksum>
            </isis-database-entry>
        </isis-database>
        <isis-database>
            <level>2</level>
            <isis-database-entry>
                <lsp-id>yyy.00-00</lsp-id>
                <sequence-number>0x419e</sequence-number>
                <checksum>0x1f24</checksum>
            </isis-database-entry>
        </isis-database>
    </isis-database-information>
    <cli>
        <banner>{master}</banner>
    </cli>
</rpc-reply>
```

and here is the query that I do, based also on related questions in stack overflow,

```
In [71]: docs = etree.fromstring(xxx)                                                                                                                 

In [72]: docs                                                                                                                                         
Out[72]: <Element rpc-reply at 0x7fc2e4c5eac8>

In [73]: docs.xpath("//isis-database-information/isis-database[level='2']/isis-database-entry")                                                       
Out[73]: []

In [74]: docs[0]                                                                                                                                      
Out[74]: <Element {http://xml.juniper.net/junos/15.1X22/junos-routing}isis-database-information at 0x7fc2e5876288>

In [76]: docs.xpath("//j:isis-database-information/j:isis-database[level='2']/j:isis-database-entry", namespaces={"j": "http://xml.juniper.net/junos/1
    ...: 5.1X22/junos-routing"})                                                                                                                      
Out[76]: []
```

I fail to understand how the namespace and Path play together.
Could you advise and tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: See here for namespaces in general: http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm See here for namespaces in lxml: https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're just missing the `j` prefix on `level`...

```xml
//j:isis-database-information/j:isis-database[j:level='2']/j:isis-database-entry
```